# Ionic v3 + MFP Project Setup - Always fetching updated plugin?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins, mfp

I am working on project which is based on Ionic-v3 and MFP version 2017090705.

I have defined the correct version in config.xml and package.json. But still whenever i am doing a clean install (i.e. removing node_modules folder and removing plugins folder), somehow the latest version of mfp getting picked.

Steps:

1. npm install
2. ionic cordova prepare

(During this step, iOS - 4.5.4 picked from config.xml and start updating plugins. But for cordova-plugin-mfp instead of 8.0.2017090705, its picking up another version with following message
 - "Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-mfp@8.0.2019050614" already fetched, using that version."
)

How could i remove the already fetched plugin dependency?

Note - Its coming even if i removed iOS platform using (ionic cordova platform rm ios). and also deleted plugins and node_modules folder.

(This started happening after i changed the Xcode from 9 to Xcode 10)

Comment: What if you remove the plugin? Do 
ionic cordova plugin remove and then add whatever version you need like so:
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp@2017090705.
And why are you using the old plugin any which ways? It is 2 years old.

Comment: @VivinK Every time i tried to remove and add plugin it picking up the "8.0.2019050614" version. But once i do a force removal of plugin and install the desired version, the version get install and can see that using "ionic cordova plugin list" as well. But now the build is getting failed and getting deprecated logs related to iOS 9.

Comment: @VivinK - As the backend is using MFP version "8.0.2017021701", i cannot increase the version at front end. I am using ionic-v3 on cordova 7.1.0 but as per new Appstore submission guideline changes, i need to build using Xcode 10. So to build project with Xcode 10 - mfp version required to be upgraded or upgrading the cordova from 7.1.0 to 8.0.0 should be sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

Try running with following commands :

- ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-mfp
- ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp@2017090705 --save